# Does DocToolChain support Python?

Tags: documentation, doctoolchain

I came across docToolChain (http://doctoolchain.org/) for generating Docs. Wanted to know if this can support other programming languages such as Python, Go etc? Or will it only support Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it does - depending on your needs :-)

When we incremented the version of docToolchain from 1.x to 2.0, the biggest feature was that the technology is now hidden behind a wrapper.
You still need java installed (v8-v14), but you don't have any code any more in your repository.

But regarding Python - it is quite likely that you want to use restructuredText as your markup language.
Until now, docToolchain focussed on AsciiDoc (based on ruby) as the markup language for your projects documentation.
There is now a feature coming up: jBake, the static site generator used by docToolchain is already able to render markdown.
But there is now also a PoC which shows that it can also render restructuredText with a little help of a small python script:

http://doctoolchain.org/multi-markup-demo/demo/asciidoc.html

Update 06.06.2023: there is a demo which also renders restructuredText: https://github.com/docToolchain/multi-markup-demo

PS: I am the maintainer of docToolchain, so my answer might be biased

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I saw your videos in YT, very helpful. Thanks a ton!